# Data not fetched in prod mode in angular 5 and firestore

Tags: firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to build a PWA using angular 5, everything works well and good(loads data from firestore) when I run it on localhost using `ng serve` , I used firebase hosting to host it and then I dont get the data from the firestore, no errors thrown in the console. I found similar issue when I do `http-server` in the `dist` directory.
[image]

Actually, when I do `http-server` on `dist` directory I get two urls, 127.0.0.1 and 10.49.92.71 . 127.0.0.1 gives me the same issue, where I dont get values from the subscribed observables... but 10.49.92.71 gives me the data  from firestore and everything works properly. Can anyone help me out? thanks!

Comment: did you correctly configured `environments/environment.prod.ts`?

Comment: yes, i used a separate project for prod env, also verified that the same is being used in prod environment.